# Updating of duplicate records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, duplicates, duplicate-data

I want to update the postal code for the same customers based on their latest purchase date.

```
Customer_code      Postal_code   last_purchase_date
12345              444555        20130131
12345              444555        20130131
12345              123456        20110131
```

As the third field postal code is outdated, i want to update it and replace it with the latest postal code which is '444555' based on the latest purchase date. because i have a few hundred thousand fields similar to this, any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT Customer_code, Postal_code, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY Customer_code ORDER BY last_purchase_date DESC)
  FROM dbo.some_table_name
)
UPDATE x SET x.Postal_code = y.Postal_code
  FROM x INNER JOIN x AS y
  ON x.Customer_code = y.Customer_code
  WHERE y.rn = 1 AND x.rn > 1
  AND COALESCE(x.Postal_code, '') <> y.Postal_code;
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help Aaron!! Thank you so much! The query worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

another possible solution without CTE:

```
update tab 
    set postal_code = 
        (select top 1 postal_code from tab x where x.customer_code = t.customer_code order by last_purchase_date desc)
    from tab t
```

Comment: What's wrong with a CTE? It's a very repeatable pattern for many similar problems, not all of them solvable by a top 1 correlated subquery.

Comment: nothing's wrong with CTEs ... I just wanted to show an alternative ... maybe someone has a similar problem with a dbms that doesn't support CTEs ... they are Microsoft specific, aren't they?

Comment: Well, the question was tagged [tag:sql-server], so unless there is a requirement to provide a database-agnostic query (which, for anything even remotely complex, isn't possible anyway), I don't see the problem with proprietary answers - especially when, as I said, they present reusable and portable patterns.

Comment: Really appreciate your help! @AaronBertrand
Thank you so much! The query worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY Postal_code ORDER BY Customer_code )
  FROM dbo.some_table_name
)

update cte set last_purchase_date='' where rn = 2
```

Update according your recuirnment.